# Changing systemfile on linux - from ext3 to ext4

Tags: linux

I would like to change file system on one of my disk.

I know steps: format, unmount, install ext4, mount, but I can't find any helpful information about it. Could you help me with it?

Comment: You simply use an fdisk tool. Mark the partition as ext4. Afterwards new files will be ext4, old files ext3. Therefore you could look for tools moving every file once.

Comment: There’s no ext3 partition type, so there’s no ext4 type. It’s called `Linux filesystem` and applies to anything from ext2 to XFS. Meaning: Nothing to change there.

Comment: Definitely do NOT need to delete / format an ext3 to migrate to ext4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete description of the process:

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/643/Migrating_a_live_system_from_ext3_to_ext4_filesystem

Comment: Yes, if the answer consists of simple googling like: "switching ext3 to ext4" and the website is the manual.